# vs 2005 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol (2)

Tags: com, visual-c++, lnk2001

"public: virtual long __stdcall PCI1761Event::GetTypeInfoCount(unsigned int *)" (?GetTypeInfoCount@PCI1761Event@@UAGJPAI@Z)

**Code**

class PCI1761Event :
    public CComObjectRoot,
    public _IAdvDIOEvents
{

public:
    BEGIN_COM_MAP(PCI1761Event)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(_IAdvDIOEvents)
    END_COM_MAP()

```
PCI1761Event(void);<br>

HRESULT  OnDiInterrupt (
    long channel,
    VARIANT * data,
    long scanStart,
    long scanCount );<br>

HRESULT OnDiStatusChange (
    long port,
    VARIANT * data,
    long scanStart,
    long scanCount );<br>

HRESULT OnDiPatternMatch (
    long port,
    VARIANT * data,
    long scanStart,
    long scanCount );<br>

HRESULT OnDeviceRemoved (
    long DeviceNumber );
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount( 
        /* [out] */ UINT *pctinfo) ;<br>

     HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo( 
        /* [in] */ UINT iTInfo,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [out] */ ITypeInfo **ppTInfo) ;

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames( 
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [size_is][in] */ LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        /* [in] */ UINT cNames,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [size_is][out] */ DISPID *rgDispId) ;

    /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke( 
        /* [in] */ DISPID dispIdMember,
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [in] */ LCID lcid,
        /* [in] */ WORD wFlags,
        /* [out][in] */ DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
        /* [out] */ VARIANT *pVarResult,
        /* [out] */ EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
        /* [out] */ UINT *puArgErr) ;
```

public:
    ~PCI1761Event(void);
};

Why????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `_IAdvDIOEvents` inteface you are trying to implement is derived from `IDispatch` and thus you have to implement `IDispatch` methods on your class too. In ATL you typically inherit your class from `IDispatchImpl<_IAdvDIOEvents, ...>` class to have the menthods implemented for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! i have implement IDispatch's methods( HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount... and so on) ,but the problem still exists. but i inherit IDispatchImpl， it works! I want to know the reason....

Comment: There was perhaps something you implemented incorrectly. Once you implement the missing methods, the respective errors go away.